# Django Create View parameters on form

Tags: django, django-generic-views

I have a Django `generic create view`

```
class TestCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = TestCreateForm

##forms.py
class TestCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Test

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TestCreateForm).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['test_field'] = Testing.objects.filter(user=user)
```

In function based views I would do like this:

```
form = TestCreateForm(request.user)
```

Now on the generic class based view do I have to overwrite, `get` and `post` method just for this?

Comment: You should check out [`CreateView` on CCBV](http://ccbv.co.uk/CreateView/). It's a good reference for finding what's available on Django's class based views. I hope you find it useful. *Full disclosure: I wrote this tool.*

Answer (score 7):

```
class TestCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = TestCreateForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self, **kwargs):
        form_kwargs = super(TestCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs(**kwargs)
        form_kwargs["user"] = self.request.user
        return form_kwargs
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to add the argument in the **init** (every time you instanciate the form) what you can do is override the get_form_kwargs from the CreateView class:

```
class TestCreateView(CreateView):
form_class = TestCreateForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = {
            'initial': self.get_initial(),
            'prefix': self.get_prefix(),
            'user': self.request.user
        }

        if self.request.method in ('POST', 'PUT'):
            kwargs.update({
                'data': self.request.POST,
                'files': self.request.FILES,
            })
        return kwargs
```